Ensuring that no two subsets have equal sums
Given a list $L$ of $n$ real numbers in $[0,1]$, I would like to ensure that there is no partition of $L$ into two subsets with an equal sum.
Deciding whether such a partition exists is a well-known NP-hard problem called Partition, but I am only interested in a sufficient condition. Specifically, I am looking for a condition $C$ such that:

Given the list $L$, the condition $C(L)$ can be checked in time polynomial in $n$ (assuming the Real RAM computational model);
If $C(L)$ is True, then $L$ has no equal-sum partition;
$C(L)$ holds for "almost all" lists, that is: if $L$ is chosen uniformly at random from the space $[0,1]^n$, then $C(L)$ holds with probability $1$.

Is there such a condition?

The numbers should be real or can they be considered rationals?

I had in mind the Real RAM model. But a solution for rationals would also be interesting.
